# Where can I see all the stackapps I have authorized?

Tags: support, stackapps

I have authorized some of the stackapps, which I need to revoke access to. But I am not able to find any place where I can see all the apps that I have authorized to.

Please let me know, where can I see this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the "apps" link on one of your site profiles:

[image: apps link in profile]

You can then use the "remove" link on any applications you wish to revoke access from.

[image: remove link for an app]