# List of OpenID authorized sites

Tags: support, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I have used my Stack Exchange account to login to a third-party site. Upon doing so, I was asked to authorize it to use my OpenID credentials from Stack Exchange.

Going to http://openid.stackexchange.com/ I can change my password, but not see a list of places that I have granted access, and more importantly revoke it, like Google does here: https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

If I go to my profile page and click on "my logins", it shows only the credentials *used to login on this site*, not the ones *issued to other sites*.

Where can I find a list of sites that are using my StackExchange openID account?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31021/what-openid-providers-should-we-feature-on-the-login-page

Comment: @random Now I am *much* more confused than when I started.

Comment: @random I think that is the opposite of what he wants. I believe he is asking how he can find out which out of network sites use his SE OpenId account rather than what OpenId providers will work on SE sites.

Comment: @JoshMein Exactly!

Comment: What do you see here? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/apps/203135

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156682/where-can-i-see-all-the-stackapps-i-have-authorized

Comment: The list of sites you've used the Stack Exchange OpenID provider with is different than the ones you've authorized to access API information via OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

Upon logging in, you should see your login history, including a list of the various sites on which you've logged in:

[image]

I'm not aware of any way to revoke OpenID access to a given service at this time. Note though that you can revoke access to apps which you've authorized to use the Stack Exchange API in your name; see: [How do you see what applications you've authorized on Stack Exchange with OAuth access?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134532/how-do-you-see-what-applications-youve-authorized-on-stackexchange-with-oauth-a)